# Node.js + Framework for RESTFul API

Tags: json, node.js, rest, cookies, express

I'm new to *Node* so maybe someone can help me in this decision, I want to create RESTFul API that are accessible from a web site and from mobile application returning JSON response.

I have decided to use the same API for the website and for the mobile applications for a maintain purpose, I went from a disastrous platform where the two logic part were separated. Also I want to use only RESTFul API without session for a scalability purpose, using an OAuth2 authentication and maybe Memcache to serve same JSON response thanks to the hash algorithm used.

I begin with Node+Express.js+MongoDB for the backend, but I have noticed that Express come with a lot of package to control and use cookie, template engine and so on...

So my question is: Express.js is the right package for my purpose? Or is better to not use this Framework? In your opinion what is the best way to achieve speed of access and speed of serving without any type of session and without any type of cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed some RESTful APIs with Express. The good thing about Express is that you don`t need to use all the additional stuff like session handling and template engines.
In addition there are some really good modules that enables you to set up an API very fast.
For example if you are using mongoose have a look at [Baucis](https://github.com/wprl/baucis).

If you still feel uncomfortable with Express, there are many other node.js frameworks for building RESTful APIs. Maybe give [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) a try?
Restify is somehow like a specialized version of Express, so it is really easy to migrate existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for **Strongloop** as well. Strongloop is a wrapper on express, but it has many features which makes it very powerful for building RESTful APIs.Please check this link https://strongloop.com/